# converting date to Jalal date in clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse, dbeaver

I use clickhouse version 22.3.15.33

In my table the dates are in a format like this: `2023-01-15`. I want to calculate the sum of a variable in my table for each Jalal month.

So first I need to convert this date to Jalal date and then get the month and then use `group by` based on the month. But using this code:

```sql
SELECT format(t.created_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd', 'fa')
from table t
```

gives me this error:

> SQL Error [1002]: ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: 172.21.16.1,
> port: 8123; Code: 43. DB::Exception: Illegal type Date of argument 1
> of function format: While processing format(created_date,
> 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'fa'). (ILLEGAL_TYPE_OF_ARGUMENT) (version 22.3.15.33
> (official build))

Comment: Add some sample table data and also specify the expected result. (Both as properly formatted text, i.e. no images, no links.) [mcve]

Comment: Unfortunatly Clickhouse does not support [Baháʼí_calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bah%C3%A1%CA%BC%C3%AD_calendar) You can use multiIf to transform gregorian calendar to Baháʼí_calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClickHouse doesn't have any built-in function to convert Georgian date to Jalali date, but you can make a function to do it following these steps:

### 1. Install Python library

```
sudo pip install jdatetime
```

### 2. Create a script to convert Georgian date to Jalali date

`sudo nano /var/lib/clickhouse/user_scripts/georgian_to_jalali.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import jdatetime
import sys

def georgian_to_jalali(date_str):
    georgian_date = jdatetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    jalali_date = jdatetime.datetime.fromgregorian(datetime=georgian_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return jalali_date


def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        date_str = str(line.rstrip())
        print(georgian_to_jalali(date_str), end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> Don't forget this file should be executable or you can do `chmod 777 georgian_to_jalali.py`

### 3. Create a ClickHouse function

`sudo nano /etc/clickhouse-server/georgian_to_jalali_function.xml`

```
<functions>
    <function>
        <type>executable</type>
        <name>georgian_to_jalali</name>
        <return_type>String</return_type>
        <argument>
            <type>String</type>
            <name>value</name>
        </argument>
        <format>TabSeparated</format>
        <command>georgian_to_jalali.py</command>
    </function>
</functions>
```

### Finally

You can run this query

```
SELECT today() as georgian_date, georgian_to_jalali(today()) as jalali_date;
```

or

```
SELECT georgian_to_jalali('2023-01-15') as jalali_date;
```

Your result looks like this picture

[image]

For more information about ClickHouse functions, you can [read](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions)

Answer (score 1):

I had a date in favor of d.m.y. I had to convert it to y-m-d format. This method worked for me.

```
SELECT arrayStringConcat(arrayReverse(splitByChar('.','30.12.1964')), '-') as date
```

Result:

```
array:1 [▼
  "date" => "1964-12-30"
]
```

Or you can use [replaceRegexpOne](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-replace-functions#replaceregexpone).

```
SELECT replaceRegexpOne(toString('30.05.1964'), '(\\d{2}).(\\d{2}).(\\d{4})', '\\3-\\2-\\1') as date
```

Result:

```
array:1 [▼
    "date" => "1964-05-30"
  ]
```

This may not be relevant to the question asked, but when I googled it, it recommended this page to me. That's why I'm writing it so that it will be useful for people who will search after me.